# Несколько GridView, включение - выключение их в зависимости от входных условий.

Tags: asp.net, c#, gridview

Еще раз Добрый вечер, продолжаю разгребать доставшийся по наследству проект, на станице имеем ( откинув все на не интересующее ) GridView и LinqDataSource, задача примерно следующая изменить GridView в зависимости от входных условий, я примерно представляю как это сделать ( если условие А верно GridViewA активен Б - не активен, ну соответственно наоборот, LinqDataSource можно использовать один данные там одни и те же ), но нет понимания как выразить это в коде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В смысле нет понимания? Вы же все написали. Проверяйте ваше условие либо в Page_Load, либо в разметке:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLists" runat="server" Visible='<%=ваш_параметр == ваше_значение %>' />
```

Comment: Как то я забыл про Visible, спасибо ) На самом деле забавно изучать Asp.net и C# ( опыта всего полгода ) на проекте на котором говнокод это еше мягко сказано, даже индусы отдыхают.

Comment: @Brodyagos, понимаю. Посмотрите в сторону Razor. Возможно не на примере этого проекта, но пригодится.

Comment: Тут к сожалению чистый Web Forms, на mvc переводить просто не реально 80мб исходников 10-ток веток и все в эксплуатации, а иного места пока не нашел)